# example command line and dataset for https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/itembased-collaborative-filtering.html

Tags: mahout

after reading https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/itembased-collaborative-filtering.html I've identified this is EXACTLY what I would like to do... however.. I don't actually have any examples to confirm this.

Can a kind sole out there please just give me a linux cmd line (preferably with a 5 line data example) of how I can run mahout with this dataset ? It's installed exactly as per the install instructions, ie via svn and maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line options are spelled out right there -- what are you looking for?
Maybe you want to read up on how you run a [Hadoop job on the command line](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/commands_manual.html#jar), which would be the rest of the command line you want.

This is also covered in detail in [Mahout in Action](http://www.manning.com/owen/).